# java.lang.StackOverflowError when trying to update any entity with @CreatedBy

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The problem is good described in [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/106312-spring-data-jpa-infinite-loop-when-updating-but-not-saving-an-auditable-object) old spring forum thread.

Now I stuck with the same problem. When I trying to update any entity with `@CreatedBy Employee employee` field from web request, then [exception](http://pastebin.com/BmQAaEpt) happens.

First 100 lines of stacktrace log:

```
2016-01-12 22:14:02.941 ERROR 8720 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(ClassTypeInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.hasPersistentEntityFor(AbstractMappingContext.java:148) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.getBeanWrapperFor(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touch(AuditingHandler.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markModified(AuditingHandler.java:134) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForUpdate(AuditingEntityListener.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor147.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:32) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(JpaFlushEntityEventListener.java:51) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1193) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1261) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:482) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy474.findByLogin(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at point.office.CurrentUserImpl.get(CurrentUserImpl.java:42) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor290.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at point.office.SpringSecurityAuditorAware.getCurrentAuditor(SpringSecurityAuditorAware.java:21) ~[bin/:na]
    at point.office.SpringSecurityAuditorAware.getCurrentAuditor(SpringSecurityAuditorAware.java:1) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touchAuditor(AuditingHandler.java:166) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touch(AuditingHandler.java:145) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markModified(AuditingHandler.java:134) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForUpdate(AuditingEntityListener.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor147.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:32) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(JpaFlushEntityEventListener.java:51) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1193) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1261) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:482) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy474.findByLogin(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at point.office.CurrentUserImpl.get(CurrentUserImpl.java:42) ~[bin/:na]
```

My `AuditorAware` implementation is:

```
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<Employee> {

    private final CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Autowired
    public SpringSecurityAuditorAware(CurrentUser currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getCurrentAuditor() {
        return currentUser.get();
    }

}
```

And my `CurrentUser` service implementation is:

```
@Service
public class CurrentUserImpl implements CurrentUser {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CurrentUserImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee get() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return null;
        }
        return employeeRepository.findByLogin(authentication.getName()).orElseGet(() -> null);
    }

}
```

And my `EmployeeRepository` is:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Optional<Employee> findByLogin(String login);
}
```

Entity which I try to update when exception occurs can be any entity with field annotated by spring's `@CreatedBy`. For example:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class Issue extends AbstractPersistable<Integer> {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Employee createdBy;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String body;

}
```

If for this entity I will do:

```
Issue issue = issueRepository.findOne(1);
issue.setBody("new issue body");
issueRepository.saveAndFlush(issue);
```

then exception happens.

I found a workaround: if I add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to my `Employee get()` method then all starting to work. But why it isn't working without it? Maybe there is bug in spring-data? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What exception do you get? Please include all relevant information in your post, and not on external sites.

Comment: I posted exception to external site because `stackoverflow.com` says that my message is too big. I think he's just jealous because my exception is `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. :)

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't blindly post anything, but strip it to the relevant lines. For a StackOverflowException, usually the first 30 - 50 lines are sufficient.

Comment: I did it at first but then I realized that in this particular case, the full stacktrace log matters. There is recursion somewhere and Spring developers must see the FULL stacktrace log to understand what is going on. So I decided to post full log instead of just part of it which doesn't show the full picture. I clearly understand the spirit of stackoverflow.com to include as many relevant info in post itself. But there was a *reason* to do otherwise! The first 50 rows don't even include 1 round of recursion.

Comment: I included first 100 lines of stacktrace log in post inself.

Answer (score 4):

I would get the current auditor from the Spring context instead of querying for it, for example:

```
@Component
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<Long> {

    @Override
    public Long getCurrentAuditor() {
        Long userId = 0L;   
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();   
        if ( securityContext.getAuthentication() != null ) {
            User user = (User) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            userId = Long.valueOf(user.getId()); 
        }
        return userId;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your example `SmartUser` is entity? In this case it must implement `Principal` interface it think. And for use `@CreatedBy` annotation `getCurrentAuditor()` must return entity and not id. I know this approach but in my case entity doesn't implement `Principal`. In long term I will refactor my code but for now the question is more about the bug with recursion and I think it is still valid.

Comment: In my case, I have AuditorAware<Long>.  You could have something else.